# Type casting error in pointer in C

Tags: c, pointers, types, casting

I can't do the type casting of the pointer.. I have found a garbage value of Y. 
Am I doing something wrong in my code?. Please help me to find my desire output

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){

    float x= 15;
    int *y;

    y=(int *)&x;

    printf("\tValue of X is : %f \n",x);
    printf("\tValue of y is : %d",*y);

    return 0;
}
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Comment: *Am I doing something wrong in my code?* -- Yes, you're lying to the compiler that a `float *` is the same as an `int *`.

Comment: Undefined behavior.

Comment: A `int` and `float` are two separate types.  They do not even have to be the same size.  Treating the address of one as the other is bound to fail.

Comment: Would you please give me the correct code??

Comment: Correct code to do what?

Comment: @ManashKumarMondal If all you want to do is store the value of a float in an int, then why are you using pointers?  Just declare an `int` and store the value.

Comment: @ManashKumarMondal What is the desired output?

Comment: "*Would you please give me the correct code?*": `y = x;`

Comment: Since this seems to be your first question on SO, please take the time for the help tour that you can find in the top row. Also, please, please, don't use a screen shot to show us textual data.

Answer (score 3):

```
float x= 15;
int *y;

y =(int *)&x;
```

Assigning the address of a `float` to a pointer to `int` is undefined behavior, they are not the same type and are not interchangeable, the only types that are allowed to do this are `char *` and `void *`.

Change to:

```
float x= 15;
char *y;

y = (char *)&x;

printf("\tValue of X is : %f \n", x);
printf("\tValue of y is : %d", (int)*(float *)y);
```

or

```
float x= 15;
void *y;

y = &x;

printf("\tValue of X is : %f \n", x);
printf("\tValue of y is : %d", (int)*(float *)y);
```

Answer (score 0):

I just did a mini program to test a guess, and I found your problem

```
#include <iostream>

union test
{
    float f;
    int i;
}Test;

int main()
{
  union test t;
  t.f = 15;
  std::cout << t.i << std::endl;
}
```

Sure enough, it prints `1097859072`.  This is because ints and floats are both 32 bit numbers, and what you've done is tell it "interpret this pattern of 0's and 1's that I saved as a float as an int instead".  Ints and floats are saved completely differently when it gets down to 0's and 1's, and even

```
int x = 10;
float y = 10;
```

will have completely different patterns of 0's and 1's despite being the same number.  What you've done is not a valid way to typecast.  [@Inline's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38835272/6179296) answer has one way to do it right, here is another:

```
  float x = 15;
  int y = (int)x;
```

*Edit:*
I should clarify that not all ints are going to be 32 bits, but I can tell that yours is through experimental evidence in my little test program.  You can use `sizeof(int)` to get the size in bytes of the datatype on your system to verify.

Comment: *This is because ints and floats are both 32 bit numbers* Where does it say that?  `int` can be as small as 16 bits.

Comment: I can tell that his ints are 32 bits because if you change my `int i` in the union to a short (which is 16 bits on my system), it gets a completely different number (0 for me).  The problem he is having only works if his int is 32 bits.

Comment: This is a _C_ question so you should provide a _C_ answer.

Comment: Union is a C data type, the only C++ part was using cout, it works the same with `printf("%d", t.i);`

Comment: " but I can tell that yours is through experimental evidence" - oh, you have access to OPs computer?

Comment: I tried it with different sizes and only got the same answer for that size.

Comment: The problem is that your answer is right until it is wrong.  Which makes it wrong.

Comment: Prove me wrong and I'll delete it then.

Answer (score 0):

```
float x= 15;
int *y;
y=(int *)&x;
...
printf("\tValue of y is : %d",*y);
```

With this code, you are telling the compiler that you want to take the *bit pattern* for the `float` value 15.0 and *interpret* that pattern as an `int`.  As others have pointed out, this code results in *undefined behavior*, meaning literally any result is possible.  `int` and `float` have different representations, they may (and on many platforms, do) have different sizes, and may have different alignment requirements.

What this will *not* do is convert the floating-point value `15.0` to the integer value `15`.

Assuming a big-endian, IEEE-754 32-bit single-precision `float`, the binary representation of `15.0` will look like this:

```
0 10000010 111000000000000000000
| |      | |                   |
| |      | +---------+---------+
| +--+---+           |
|    |               +----------- binary fraction 1.1112 (normalized)
|    +--------------------------- exponent (3, excess 127 notation)
+-------------------------------- sign bit
```

which just also happens to be the bit pattern for the *integer* value `1097859072`.

If you want to convert floating-point `15.0` to integer `15`, you simply need to do the following:

```
float x = 15.0;
int y = x;    // no pointers involved at all
```

C will automatically convert the floating point value `15.0` (represented as `010000010111000000000000000000002`) to the integer value `15` (represented as `000000000000000000000000000011112`)

Note that in this conversion, the fractional part is simply discarded; you will effectively be rounding towards 0.

Answer (score -1):

You're trying to cast a pointer-type into a pointer of another type.

In order to understand your fail you need to understand how the memory of a computer works. I'll try to explain you that in the shortest and simplest way as I can.

A sequence of bits can be interpreted in different way:

```
x: 01000010
```

Each *cell* of memory in RAM has a meaning given by the variable type.

So, for example:

- If `x` is a *integer* the value `01000010` will be interpreted as integer number: *66*
- If `x` is a *char* the value will be interpreted as a character *B*, and so on.

### Wrong in your code

You've allocated a integer number in memory, so:

```
x: 15.0f // In decimal base, floating point
```

If you access to that memory with a pointer with is a float pointer, like you case:

```
float* y = (float*)&x
```

Then the *same* sequence of bit will be interpreted as integer value.

Indeed, a floating point has a standard way to be represented in bits form: [wiki FP standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point).

The 754 standard stores the value 15 as:

```
01000001011100000000000000000000
```

Which is 15.0 in floating point representation, but *1097859072* as integer expression.

You can test it on [DecimalConversion](http://www.exploringbinary.com/binary-converter/).

Comment: All this is of no relevance and possibly wrong, depending on the implementation. OP invokes UB, 'nuff said.

Answer (score -3):

`y=(int *)&x;` if you do something like this value that `&f` references will not be converted to `float`. You will get `float` pointer, that points to `int`.

This is right way:

```
int main()
{
    float x= 15;
    int *y = malloc( sizeof(int) ); // Allocate memory for int
    *y  =  int(x); // Convert to int and set as value which y pointing

    printf("\tValue of X is : %f \n",x);
    printf("\tValue of y is : %d",*y);

    free(y); // Free heap allocated memory
}
```

Also you can some information about `float` and `int` realizations

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_(computer_science)

Comment: Why even create a pointer? `int y = (int)x;` is all you need.

Comment: @NathanOliver because question creator need "pointer casting".

Comment: Where does he say that?

Comment: @NathanOliver -> `I can't do the type casting of the pointer.`

Comment: NEW and PRINTF together, why?

Comment: This is not C . And the second sentence is completely wrong.